# Display Dock on the main screen on left when second screen is arranged to left

Tags: mac, display, dock

I've this arrangment of screens, and I've set the dock to stay on the left side.

The problem is that the dock goes on the second screen, while i want to keep it on the main one (the one with the white bar basically).

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: System Prefs > Mission Control > Displays have separate Spaces. Checked, the dock will follow you, unchecked it will stay on the primary monitor.

Comment: well, no. if the dock is on the left it goes on the second screen, or am I miss something? Only the top bar remains in the main screen

Comment: ah - you have the dock vertical? Then yes, it will always go to the extreme edge, it can't stop in the middle.

Comment: wow, nice to know, i think that a lot of people use it on the left, and probably those people are right handed, so the mac cannot stay on the right since using an external keyboard and mouse would be complicated (i keep hitting the mac with the mouse). @apple: think about that ;)

Comment: I've never actually met anyone who used the dock vertically, not in 25 years of using Macs. We oldies just leave it where it is, at the bottom ;-)

Comment: I'm a special guy, mom always said so.. seriously, on the small screen it saves a lot of space since the screen is rectangular with short edes on the sides. even on windows i used to do that :) . If you have a dock that autohides then it may be the same, don't know

Answer (score 4):

With the screen arrangement below you can accomplish what you want. However, with this arrangement it is not that intuitive to move with the mouse from one screen to the other. I have my MacBook sitting to the left of, and slightly lower than my monitor so it did not take too long to get used to it.

[image: Screen arrangement]

Comment: I think this is the only solution. If the displays are alongside each other, then "Dock left" is at the left hand end of the entire display surface. However, I'd recommend putting the Dock on the right. Most apps have toolbars on the left hand side, and the Dock can keep popping up when you're trying to select them.